# .remove() is not a function error in Photoshop CC 2017 ExtendScript Tool Kit

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to modify original PSD and then delete the original one and only want to save as a new jpg. My code is working fine with this line:

```html
activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES); // Close Original Image
```

But when I replace above line with this line:

```html
psd.remove(); // I want to delete Original file
```

It giving me `remove() is not a function` error.

Here is the complete script. I have tired to read Photoshop JS Guide 2015 and also google this issue but I didn't find any answer.

```html
var defaultRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits; 
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

if (documents.length >= 1){

var hres = 0;
var vres = 0;
var OldName = activeDocument.name.substring(0, activeDocument.name.indexOf('.'));
var CurrentFolder = activeDocument.path;
var psd = app.activeDocument;
hres = activeDocument.width;
vres = activeDocument.height;

activeDocument.selection.selectAll();

if (activeDocument.layers.length >1) {
 activeDocument.selection.copy(true);
}

else{
 if (activeDocument.layers.length =1) {
 activeDocument.selection.copy(false);
 }
}

psd.remove(); // I want to delete Original file
       
var newDoc = documents.add(hres, vres, 72, OldName, NewDocumentMode.RGB, DocumentFill.WHITE);

newDoc.paste();

jpgFile = new File(CurrentFolder + "/" + OldName+ ".jpg" );
jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
jpgSaveOptions.quality = 12;
newDoc.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true,   Extension.LOWERCASE);

}
```

Comment: clearly a `document` doesn't have a remove method

Comment: How do I have a remove method. Photoshop JS guide didn't talk anything about remove methods. I tried `psd.remove(psd);`,`psd.remove(File);`,`psd.remove(activeDocument);` any other combination but all are giving me same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 srcDoc.activeLayer.remove();
```

Will delete the active layer. There's no .remove() method to delete a file.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the thread, but hope this helps someone else.

The remove method expects a file location.  You can accomplish removing the original file like this:

```
var activeDoc = app.activeDocument;
var docPath = new Folder(activeDoc.path);
var psd = new File(docPath + "/" + activeDoc.name);
...
psd.remove();
```

Edit: Meant to also include a link to this handy ESTK reference doc where I learned about working with the File object: http://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html?highlight=delete